# Hibernate LazyInitializationException thrown when called through Restful web service

Tags: hibernate, rest, spring-mvc, lazy-initialization

I'm having a weird problem. I have implemented a feature in the project i'm working on using JSPs. Now  I have a new requirement where I have to implement the same feature as a REST service. I'm using the same Service and DAO methods that works perfectly fine with the JSP client but when i'm accessing it through the web service I'm getting LazyInitializationException on the mappings that I have.

Here is the Web Service GET method.

```
@GET
@Path("/{test_id}")
@Produces("application/json")
public TestInfo getTestInfo(@PathParam("test_id") long test_id) {
TestInfo info = null;
    try {
        info = service.getTest(test_id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return info;
}
```

The getTest() method works absolutely fine when the client is JSP. The stackTrace is as follows.

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.spaneos.ias.pojo.Question.answers, no session or session was closed
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:368)
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:111)
at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:186)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.iterator(Lister.java:267)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Lister$CollectionLister.iterator(Lister.java:254)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:118)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:144)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:685)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:143)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:685)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:54)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:157)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:144)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:685)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:143)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:343)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:582)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:325)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:483)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:308)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:163)
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONMarshaller.marshallToJSON(BaseJSONMarshaller.java:106)
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider.writeTo(JSONRootElementProvider.java:143)
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:157)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1479)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:233)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Can anyone please help how to return a mapped object (Loaded with many collections) using web service? 
Please let me know if I have to give more details.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to access part of your model that was not fetched during the transaction.  The answers field of the Question model can only be accessed before the transaction is closed.

So you can either :

1. Eagerly load the answers of the Question model (see hibernate documentation)
2. Access answers during transaction to put them in a DTO or example, which would be the prefered way.  You should not keep a reference to model object after a transaction has been closed.

Comment: Thanks @thebignet. I took the second (and preferred) method using a DTO. But somehow i'm not able to get rid of the LazyInitializationException though. I have posted another question for the same. Could you please look into it and suggest something? Here is the Link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737476/dozer-throwing-lazyinitializationexception